# how to get the Order Id in the success page in razorpay using laravel 7

Tags: laravel, razorpay

I'm using Razorpay in **laravel 7**

i successfully got the **razorpay paymentid, razorpay orderid, razorpay signature** in my success page.

But i need to get the **orderid** which i randomly generated before make payment in razorpay, in my success page. i.e i want to get notes of razorpay in my successpage

**my code is,**

```
"notes": {
        "address": "{{$response['address']}}",
        "merchant_order_id": "{{$response['merchant_order_id']}}"
    },
```

i want to get that **merchant_order_id** in my success page.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your order_id to view after you generated then pass it in the Razorpay script order_description. Or you can use the session to store the order_id.